# Image flipping, dynamic UVunwrap with Geometry Node

Tags: animation, uv, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I have a `rectangle3.1` object defined from the Geometry Node with a modifier like this:

[image]

More simply, we are only interested in these nodes: (the blurred nodes are only `set position` nodes)
Note that the Geometry is created from a rectangle (`Quadrilateral`) which is rounded on the corners (`Filet Curve`) and then filled (`Fill Curve`). We then associate a Material from `Group Input` and pass the Geometry as a parameter to `Group Output`. We also pass the output of `UV Unwrap` to `Group Output` under the name `UV`.

[image]

In the modifier settings I have linked the UV output to a `UVwrap` variable.

[image]

In the Material definition I link the `vector` property of the `UVwrap` variable to `vector` of the image:

[image]

So far, everything is working fine but when I create an animation that uses the rectangle settings, the rectangle image suddenly flips over at certain frames.

**[See the result of the animation](https://1drv.ms/v/s!Ag4CzKQ76zeggsd8adlxdWJXU3qSvA?e=jw1mMR)**

**frame 31:**
[image]

**frame 32:**
[image]

**frame 33:**
[image]

**Why do I behave this way and how do I keep the image from turning around?**